# vhdl recursive instantiation with packages

Tags: vhdl

I have a system where a design and a subdesign inside it are different architectures 
of the same entity; so this is a case of recursive instantiation. First the setup :

```
-- common entity
entity MyEntity is port(A : in  integer; B : out integer);end;
-- first architecture
architecture MyArc1 of MyEntity is begin B<=A+1;end;
-- second architecture intneded to include the first
architecture MyArc2  of MyEntity is
 component MyEntity port(A : in  integer; B : out integer);end component;
 signal C : integer;
begin
 u1 : MyEntity port map (A,C);
 u2 : MyEntity port map (C,B);
end;
```

the above works fine with Modelsim. The problem comes up when I try to move the
component declaration into a package :

```
-- package that declares components
package MyPackage is
 component MyEntity port(A : in  integer; B : out integer);end component;
end;
-- second architecture as above but using the package
use work.MyPackage.all;
architecture MyArc2  of MyEntity is
 -- component declaration moved into package
 signal C : integer;
begin
 u1 : MyEntity port map (A,C);
 u2 : MyEntity port map (C,B);
end;
```

For some reason Modelsim doesn't like this :
Identifier "myentity" does not identify a component declaration

I don't see why it has trouble with this now. My experience with Modelsim is
that it is good at supporting the standard; so is there a subtlety here or does
Modelsim have a problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Try a qualified name : u1:MyPackage.MyEntity to see if MyEntity (the component) is being hidden by MyEntity (the entity). In version 1, MyEntity (the component) is the most recent (most local) declaration; not true in V2.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. MyPackage.MyEntity didn't work but work.MyPackage.MyEntity did! There's some strange scoping logic here...but at least it can be made to work...